# What is " killer adversary for quick sort "?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I have read the quick sort. We use the pivot element irrespective of other data set in array. As far as, I know; this killer adversary tells the input that lead to quadratic time complexity (practically). But how?

Edit: These following lines from the  [published paper](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf) on Adversary killer for Quick Sort did not understand.

" **Initially the adversary makes all items gas.When two gas items are compared, one gets “frozen” into
a definite “solid” value, greater than any already solid value. Then the operands are compared afresh.
When a solid item is compared to a gas item, it compares low.When two solid items are compared, the
answer depends on the frozen values.**"

[Link to adversary killer for quick sort](http://research.swtch.com/qsort)

Comment: The paper explains how, and it does it better than the format of this site would allow. Perhaps if a specific place in the paper was unclear for a specific reason, there could be an on-topic discussion.

Comment: @n.m. perhaps, you are right, but  I didn't understand the following lines from mentioned paper.

" Initially the adversary makes all items gas.When two gas items are compared, one gets “frozen” into a definite “solid” value, greater than any already solid value. Then the operands are compared afresh.
When a solid item is compared to a gas item, it compares low.When two solid items are compared, the
answer depends on the frozen values."

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36383788/edit) your question and put this information in.

Comment: I believe I may be late for the party but for the sake of anybody who may come across this in the future, [here's an actual C# implementation][1] and detailed explanation of the point this paper is trying to put across. It really helped me to understand what's going on here.


  [1]: http://igoro.com/archive/quicksort-killer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of "gas" and "solid" as labels that the adversary applies to the array items in order to remember which items were already seen by quicksort. The adversary works like this:

- the adversary gives an array of items labelled "gas" and with values of positive infinity to quicksort;
- quicksort selects which items it wishes to compare;
- the adversary may intervene, change a "gas" label into a "solid" label, give the item a finite integer value, and then allow quicksort to proceed.

The procedure is designed so that an item can only be frozen if quicksort didn't move it yet. Thus, if we take the items after all of them are solid, arrange them in their original order, and give them to quicksort without the adversary, quicksort will use exactly the same sequence of comparisons as it did when the adversary was present.

Comment: "the adversary gives an array of items labelled "gas" and with values of positive infinity to quicksort;" 
what do you want to convey from this sentence?

Comment: I have tried to explain how the adversary works. I'm sorry if I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

The paper assumes unusual capabilities on the side of the adversary: **the adversary has control over the comparison function** invoked by `quicksort`. In other words, the adversary can not only provide a maliciously crafted data array in the beginning, it can adapt its behaviour during the `quicksort` run.

Given this power, the adversary can effectively construct an input array 'on-the-fly' (as it is observed by `quicksort`), where each pivot is selected to have a value higher than all previously observed elements. This way, `n` pivots are chosen, and each one is compared to `O(n)` elements, yielding the runtime of `O(n^2)`.

The 'on-the-fly' capability allows to also break randomized versions of `quicksort`. However, unless you provide an online sorting service where the attacker provides both the input and the comparison method, you don't need to worry about this attack.

Comment: I can totally see myself writing a similar 'adversary' by accident. I don't think you need any malicious intent to hit this.

Comment: @Rotsor: indeed, if you use a comparison function that takes `O(n)`, you'll get `O(n^2)` just as well. However, when comparing runtimes of sorting algorithms, one usually assumes that a comparison takes `O(1)`.

Comment: that's different because there you would get `O(n*log(n))` comparisons on average so the promise of `qsort` is not broken.